# Keep first option when appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.my-dropdown > select').append(optionArray);
```

HTML

```
<select><option>Select a cake</option></select>
```

How do I keep select a cake which is the first option while appending the other option?

Comment: Shouldn't append do this automatically, as 'append' adds to the end of the array?

Comment: If you are appending like this then first option will always remain the first item. What is going wrong? what is `optionArray`?

Comment: Your code should work fine. Please show your optionArray

Answer (score 0):

Try this......

```
<select><option selected="selected">Select a cake</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
$('.my-dropdown > select').append(optionArray);
```

write line like this:

```
$('.my-dropdown > select > option:first').attr('selected','selected');
```